# sed Removing whitespace around certain character

Tags: sed, whitespace

what would be the best way to remove whitespace only around certain character. Let's say a dash - `Some- String- 12345- Here` would become `Some-String-12345-Here`. Something like `sed 's/\ -/-/g;s/-\ /-/g'` but I am sure there must be a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean all whitespace, not just spaces, then you could try `\s`:

```
echo 'Some- String- 12345- Here' | sed 's/\s*-\s*/-/g'
```

Output:

```
Some-String-12345-Here
```

Or use the `[:space:]` character class:

```
echo 'Some- String- 12345- Here' | sed 's/[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*/-/g'
```

Different versions of sed may or not support these, but GNU sed does.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
's/ *- */-/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use awk as well

```
$ echo 'Some   - String-    12345-' | awk -F" *- *" '{$1=$1}1' OFS="-"
Some-String-12345-
```

if its  just "- " in your example

```
$ s="Some- String- 12345-"
$ echo ${s//- /-}
Some-String-12345-
```