# How to remove white space after an alphanumeric that changes throughout the document

Tags: whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a text file, part of which has the following format

```
exon_id=OFAS000007-RA-EXON02;   transcript=OFAS000007-RA;
exon_id=OFAS000007-RA-EXON05;   transcript=OFAS000007-RA;
exon_id=OFAS000008-RA-EXON03;   transcript=OFAS000008-RA;
exon_id=OFAS000017-RA-EXON07;   transcript=OFAS000017-RA;
```

I need to remove the white space in between the two columns. A simple search and replace will not work, as there are many other columns in this file with text, numbers, and symbols that are subsequently followed by ";".

I know that any find and replace approach will need to take the "EXON" part of the first string and the "transcript" part of the second, but how am I to indicate numbers that vary from the "EXON"?

EDIT: The tab-delimited text file has too much information to even insert a part of here; there are too many additional columns that I don't need to modify in any way. I simply need to combine the two columns mentioned here, leaving all the others separate but in the same file, same order. Here is what the desired output should look like when combining the two columns:

```
exon_id=OFAS000007-RA-EXON02;transcript=OFAS000007-RA;
exon_id=OFAS000007-RA-EXON05;transcript=OFAS000007-RA;
exon_id=OFAS000008-RA-EXON03;transcript=OFAS000008-RA;
exon_id=OFAS000017-RA-EXON07;transcript=OFAS000017-RA;
```

Comment: could you please provide examples of what you do not intend to match? *It is not clear to me if the content of the exon/transcript field matters.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove whitespace before a field using AWK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409060/remove-whitespace-before-a-field-using-awk)

Comment: There are numerous ways to do with sed and awk. already few has been answered in tag whitespace and removing-whitespace which you have used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552842/sed-removing-whitespace-around-certain-character

Answer (score 0):

On *linux* I would use **sed**:

```
sed -i '/^exon_id/s/;[\t ]*transcript=/;transcript/' file_name
         ^-------------------- match lines starting with 'exon_id
                    ^ -------- match lines with ;<spaces>transcript=
```

An alternative, if you plan to match *EXONXX*, is:

```
sed -i '/EXON[0-9][0-9]/s/;[\t ]*transcript=/;transcript/' file_name
```

---

**ETA**: This expression can be refined, perhaps you should provide some examples of what you don't want to match.

Comment: The file has too much information to even insert a part of here. These are two columns of many. I simply need to combine these two columns, leaving all the others separate but in the same file, same order. Here is what the desired output should look like when combining the two colymns:  `exon_id=OFAS000007-RA-EXON02;transcript=OFAS000007-RA;
exon_id=OFAS000007-RA-EXON05;transcript=OFAS000007-RA;
exon_id=OFAS000008-RA-EXON03;transcript=OFAS000008-RA;
exon_id=OFAS000017-RA-EXON07;transcript=OFAS000017-RA;`

Comment: @MichaelForthman both the above one-liners produce your desired output, the problem is `pattern-matching` requires setting the right level of fine-grained detail in the regular expression. That is why I need to know **what is unique about the lines that you want to match?**